# How to avoid warning "No queryConverter defined, using default converter" in solr search

Tags: solr, sunspot-solr

How to avoid warning No queryCOnverter defined in solr search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid this issue Please add the patch below :

```
diff --git solrconfig.xml solrconfig.xml
index 37b7913..dd9bb62 100644
--- solrconfig.xml
+++ solrconfig.xml
@@ -570,6 +570,8 @@
```

File :  solrconfig.xml , Add code below to `</searchComponent>` code

```
  <queryConverter name="queryConverter" class="solr.SpellingQueryConverter"/>

   <!-- a search component that enables you to configure the top results for
    a given query regardless of the normal lucene scoring.-->
   <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
```

Thanks!!!